# How to bind javascript action with using require js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

in my new project, there are a lots of button / a elements ( they may load from ajax ) in the website. In previous approach, I write all javascript in a single file to trigger those button / a elements.

For Example,

in my html markup:

```
 // Trigger "STH.foo" function
 <a href="/hello.html" class="action-button" data-action="STH.foo">foo</a>
 <button data-some-value="foo" class="action-button" data-action="STH.foo">foo</button>

 // Trigger "STH.blah" function
 <a href="/hello.html" class="action-button" data-action="ABC.blah">foo</a>
 <button data-some-value="foo" class="action-button" data-action="ABC.blah">foo</button>
```

what in my javascript

```
 var STH = {};
 // where foo dependence fancybox.js ( Let's say it needed fancybox.js )
 STH.foo = function(){ ... blah blah blah ... };
 // where blah dependence fancybox.js ( Let's say it needed bootstrap.js )
 ABC.blah = function(){ ... blah blah blah ... };
 // finally
 $( function(){
      $('.action-button').on('click', function(){
          STH.run($(this).attr('data-action'), $(this).data());
      }
 }
```

To handle the dependencies before, what I did is group all `fancybox.js` and `bootstrap.js` in to single file, let's say I named it `library.js`

But what I found is the code became long and long, so for the new project, I started to use `require.js`. So far the feeling is quite good. But I don't know how to handle well for my pervious `action-botton`.

Suppose, `ABC` and `STH` is different namespace, so I separated into 2 javascript files `ABC.js` and `STH.js`. Once the button / a elements need it, I do ...

```
 require(['fancybox'], function(){
     STH.blah();
 })
```

My questions is, any idea to write a handler to controll all my action-botton, to let them automatically load required javascript file and trigger correct action?

Comment: Any luck with this? How'd you manage later

Comment: haha, not ever thought months later has people leave me a comment.

approach 1:

also attributes for javascript action dom, like `data-*`, write a module. listen on their clicks, use the attribute to determine which invoked modules have to calls.

approach 2
backbone, emberjs, angularjs, flightjs ... etc